# Como mandar archivo en petición post vía ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Lo que ocupo es mandar desde javascript un archivo sin que contenga html, dicho de otra forma de forma automática, desde una especie de form data o de la forma posible.

Hasta ahorita tengo lo siguiente

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: base_url+"index.php/xml_seminuevos/envio_automatico/",
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $.each(data.agencias, function(index, value){
                if(value['saved'] == "ko"){
                    $("#resultados").append("<h1>Error en la generacion del archivo para la sucursal "+value['Renault_id']+"</h1>");        
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#resultados").append("<h1>Archivo Generado con exito para la sucursal "+value['Renault_id']+"</h1>");
                    $("#resultados").append("<h1>Comenzando envio para la sucursal  "+value['Renault_id']+"</h1>");


                }

        })
        .fail(function() {
            $("#resultados").append("<h1>Error al ejecutar la funcion</h1>");
        });
```

Aquí lo que hace es que en la función `envio_Automatico` genera un zip  y quisiera saber como madar ese zip que acabo de generar en otra petición ajax sin intervención del usuario se me ocurrio que con un form data se puede pero no se que colocar como valor.

Comment: tu subes el archivo en un input?

Comment: Creando tu archivo, entonces lo almacenas momentaneamente para después enviarlo a otra parte mediante ajax? y porque no envías unicamente la URL de donde esta contenido el zip? para que lo descarguen

Comment: El problema es que necesito mandarlo a una api rest full no lo van a descargar solo se manda para que lo analicen de echo desde postman ya me salio, seleccionando form-data y en el campo de tipo file pero no he podido replicar esto desde javascript el detalle es que esto debería de ser una rutina automática donde no interviene alguna persona.